# Is libstdc++'s facet implementation thread safe?

Tags: c++

I think lots of the libstdc++'s facet implementation depends on the C function. For example: for the codecvt facet's implementation (https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/config/locale/gnu/codecvt_members.cc#L53)

```cpp
codecvt_base::result
  codecvt<wchar_t, char, mbstate_t>::
  do_out(state_type& __state, const intern_type* __from, ...)
  {
      __c_locale __old = __uselocale(_M_c_locale_codecvt);
      // do something
      __uselocale(__old);
  }
```

It calles the __uselocale defined at glibc (https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/locale/uselocale.c) to switch the C-language locale before and after the real processing logic.

However, seems there is no lock in the whole logic. And I don't see the lock in the wrapper functions (such as codecvt::out defined in https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/codecvt.h#L124). Therefore I think the `__uselocale` might impact other thread's locale setting and may cause data-race.

Is my understand wrong or it is a defect of libstdc++?

Thanks!

Comment: [`uselocale`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2008edition/functions/uselocale.html) sets a per-thread global locale. The comments in the linked glibc function also say that. So there is no lock needed since no shared state is accessed.